# Seaborn BoxPlot and log axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I'm facing a problem on ticks since hours now.

I would like to plot a boxplot with log scaling but it seems there is 2 issues :

> Data has no positive values, and therefore cannot be log-scaled.

And

> Attempted to set non-positive xlimits for log-scale axis; invalid limits will be ignored.

Her is my code :

```
# Import librairies
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# Undersampling the DataFrame through columns because too big
sampling_factor = 50

all_frame_inverted_undersampled = all_frame_inverted.take([x for x in range(0,all_frame_inverted.shape[1], sampling_factor)], axis=1)

# Settings the canvas
fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6))
ax.set_xlabel('Cycles') 
ax.set_ylabel('Measures')

# setting log axis
ax.set_xscale('log')

# Plotting
g = sns.boxplot(data=all_frame_inverted_undersampled , palette='rainbow', orient="v", ax=ax)

# Showing
plt.tight_layout()
```

Here is the DataFrame's for the 3 first lines : 
[image]

And here, what I get :
[image]

I've tried many things like setting : 
`ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xmajor_formatter) with LogFormatter`

I've tried `symlog`, the error message disapear but the results is quite the same.

I tried also : `ax.set_xscale('symlog', linthreshy=1e3)`

> EDIT
>   I'm trying to get, on the x axis, ticks formatted as in the plot below :
>   [image]
>
> EDIT 2 :  Here is a minimal exemple of my code :
>
> ```
> # Preprocessing and Cleaning data
> import numpy as np
> import pandas as pd
>
> # Data Visualization
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
> %matplotlib inline
>
> # Data Analysis & Visualization
> import seaborn as sns
>
> # Data
> data= [[181.08, 180.23, 181.60, 178.05, 172.33, 175.50, 169.81, 167.10, 166.92, 166.10, 159.69], 
>        [144.94,140.30,140.15,146.07,143.90,143.06,139.74,139.97,144.06,145.13,146.34],
>        [176.25,195.43,217.50,183.75,174.74,169.11,166.81,161.82,164.08,162.25,166.72],
>        [198.31,221.16,214.19,209.06,202.08,180.08,185.79,181.73,178.95,179.53,189.08],
>        [167.81,166.28,144.18,138.22,139.48,144.66,141.34,141.60,146.53,145.84,155.20]]
>
> # Data to Dataframe
> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['M01', 'M02', 'M03', 'M04', 'M05'], 
>                   columns=[8796, 60501505, 142252576, 224057457, 305801670, 387546170, 487628661, 609874323, 732114489, 854385341, 1190477590])
>
> # Boxplot calculated for each cycle through all structures Mxx
> fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6))
> ax.set_xlabel('Cycles') 
> ax.set_ylabel('Measures')
> ax.set_xscale('symlog')
> plt.xticks(rotation=45)
> sns.boxplot(data=df, palette='rainbow', orient="v", ax=ax)
>
>
> # Showing plot
> plt.tight_layout()
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> Here is what I can do with Plotly, I want this result using boxplot
>   please :
>
> ```
>  # Interactive Data Visualization needs : pip install plotly & pip install cufflinks
> from plotly import __version__
> from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
> import cufflinks as cf
> df.iplot(kind='box', xTitle='Cycles', yTitle='Measures', logx=True)
> ```
>
> [image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: I do not understand the issue. Since you are aware that you cannot use a logscale for negative data you chose to use symlog. This is good, but then the question stops. What is bad about using symlog? In how far is the result not what you expect?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for your answer. First of all, I don't have negative numbers so I don't understand why I need symlog. Furthermore, the ticks here are not correctly formatted. It's not readeable now as it is.

Comment: Well for a start, provide a [mcve] of the issue. I can't know what data you have, you need to provide a code with the data that is runnable and shows the issue. It could be that you cannot use seaborn boxplot for the data you have, but one cannot know that without runnable code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, sorry for the delay, I was working on something else. I'll put as an edit the exemple and a jupyter notebook one also. Thanks